# Установить картинку через галерею с помошью permission Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

нужно при нажатии кнопки установить imageView из галереи
подскажите что не так с кодом, выскакивает ошибка при нажатии кнопки

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    private final  int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 3;
    private final  int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 2;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {   //проверка для андроид 5...
                    /*takePic();*/

                    return;
                }

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                }else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 13);

                }

            }

        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent takePictureIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, takePictureIntent);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != takePictureIntent) {
            Uri selectedImage = takePictureIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            assert selectedImage != null;
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 13: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                }else{

                }return;

            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storegeDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storegeDir);

        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "application.com.decemper06.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка то?

Comment: Process: application.com.decemper06, PID: 27416
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: у вас, если нет разрешения на чтение внешнего хранилища, то запрашивается разрешение на доступ к камере

Answer (score 0):

Вот 100% рабочий пример:

```
private String imagePath;
private ImageView imgview;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 911;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestStoragePermission();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
    });
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Выберите изображение"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

        Picasso.with(this)
            .load(new File(imagePath))
            .resize(200, 200)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imgview);
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(context, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Предоставлены права на чтение.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Права на чтение не были предоставлены.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

//Requesting permission
private void requestStoragePermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Comment: что за класс Picasso?

Comment: Это библиотека. Служит для загрузки изображений как локально, так и из сети. Более подробно тут -> http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/picasso.php

Comment: @Kramk, если мой ответ оказался верным и/или полезным, пожалуйста, отметьте его как "верный".

Comment: @sergei1094, если уж советуете использовать библиотеку - укажите это в ответе с офф. ссылкой на неё: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @sergei1094, установил библиотеку пикассо но при запуске вылетает ошибка 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at application.com.decemper06.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)

Comment: @woesss Я ничего не советую. На сайте Климова есть ресурс на офф сайт. Я предложил просто подробнее узнать библиотеку на русскоязычном сайте.

Comment: @Kramk , а `button` у вас инициализирован?

Comment: да, само собой, гляньте код еще раз, может чего упустили ?

Comment: У вас эта ошибка вылетает именно при открытии приложения? Или по нажатию кнопки? Опишите всю суть, что делаете и как, зачем и куда...гадать сложно. Мой ответ изъят с рабочего приложения. При запуске данного класса, Intent должен запросить у вас разрешение на чтение из ФС.

Comment: sergei1094, у меня та же ошибка, она выпадает после выбора картинки, перед ее загрузкой в imageview. Написано, что метод getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA) указывает на пустой объект